# Node js with fs and setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fs

I have a error "Callback must be a function" with this code

```
function saveCallback() {console.log("Sauvegarde du json")}
bot.login(TOKEN)
var test = '{"channelAlias":[]}'
setInterval(fs.writeFile('stockage.json',test,saveCallback), 300000)
```

Comment: Can you share exactly what error says or other information provided in error. There are two callbacks, for setInterval and fs.writeFile. Which one are you taking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function saveCallback() {console.log("Sauvegarde du json")}
bot.login(TOKEN)
var test = '{"channelAlias":[]}'
setInterval(() => { 
  fs.writeFile('stockage.json',test,saveCallback)
}, 300000)
```

`setInterval`'s signature is setInterval(callbackFUNCTION, time)

Comment: isn't fs.writeFile() a function?

Comment: This might had solved the problem, but still doesn't tell what was wrong with direct call. Try this `setInterval(console.log("Hello"), 1000);`, no error. Then what was wrong with `fs.writeFile()`.

Comment: @NAVIN ```fs.writeFile``` is a function BUT ```fs.writeFile()``` is a ```void```. So 300 secs later ```void``` will be called and that is obviously the ```"Callback must be a function"``` error.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs')
function saveCallback() {console.log("Sauvegarde du json")}
var test = '{"channelAlias":[]}'
setInterval(function(){fs.writeFile('stockage.json',test,saveCallback)}, 3000)
```

please see the difference

below will NOT GIVE ERROR

```
function willReturnFunction(){
    return function(){
        console.log("welcome")
    }
}
setInterval(willReturnFunction(),1000)
```

below will GIVE ERROR (**your case**)

```
function willNotReturnFunction(){
    //returning something other than funtion
    // like fs.wrtiteFile function
    return "some string"
}
setInterval(willNotReturnFunction(),1000)
```

I hope this helps! NAVIN

Comment: I'm not giving down vote, but how this is solution for problem listed. `fs.writeFile` is a function. Then why does still error that it's not a function?

Comment: there is difference between function(){fs.writeFile()} &directly passing fs.writeFile().... It is that what you were trying to do will invoke fs.writeFile() as soon as it executes setInterval. and fs.WriteFile does not return a function so as giving error  callback must be a "function". What i did is give it a function. So the only difference is,,... in one you invoke function yourself and in other you give function to  setinterval so that it does what it wants

Comment: `fs.writeFile()` doesn't return anything, it takes a callback function for follow up. `fs.writeFile()` is asynchronous function and all asynchronous return no value, some might return `promise` but `promise` is a function. You tried to trick with `willNotReturnFunction()` by returning a value, but `fs.writeFile` does not return a value. If your do `willNotReturnFunction() {console.log("some string");}` and return nothing then `setInterval()` will not give error. Yes it will be invoked right then and not as from setInterval but no error. Try this out `setInterval(console.log("Hello"),1000)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const saveCallback = () => {
    console.log(`Sauvegarde du json`)
}
bot.login(TOKEN)
const test = `{ "channelAlias": [] }`
setInterval(() => fs.writeFile(`./stockage.json`, test, saveCallback), 300000)
```

Comment: I'm not giving down vote, but how this is solution for problem listed. `fs.writeFile` is a function. Then why does still error that it's not a function?

Comment: Please make this into an answer, this does not look like a solution.